# using remote json file in php code

Tags: php, json

To get the details with regards to "ID", I have prepared the following PHP with json array inside it. It is working perfectly.

```
<?php
$json = '{"records": 
       [
         {"Name":"Jhon", "Age":"45", "id":"101"},
         {"Name":"Bhil", "Age":"42", "id":"102"},
         {"Name":"Tone", "Age":"41", "id":"103"},
       ]
    }';

$myjson = json_decode($json, true);  
  foreach ( $myjson['records'] as $row ) {  
                        if ($row['id'] =='216') { 
                         echo 'Details of  login id:&nbsp;'.  $row['id']. '<br/>';
                         foreach ( $row as $field => $value ) {  // loop the fields
                               // do the work here
                             }
                   }
         }
?>
```

Now for one of my project, i have  to crete arround 750 Ids with various vaules. 
Putting all these inside php file may slow down the page loading.

Hence, I have craeted json file(remote): **xyz.com/dir/jsondata.json**

Kindly guide me, how to incopporate the above json file in the php code.

Comment: [`file_get_contents() `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) should work fine for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch the file using `$data=file_get_contents('xyz.com/dir/jsondata.json');` and then use the decode the json and loop through it

```
$myjson = json_decode($data, true);  
  foreach ( $myjson['records'] as $row ) {  
                        if ($row['id'] =='216') { 
                         echo 'Details of  login id:&nbsp;'.  $row['id']. '<br/>';
                         foreach ( $row as $field => $value ) {  // loop the fields
                               // do the work here
                             }
                   }
         }
```

Comment: My question is: whether the remote json file is fast loading comaparing to json array inside php?

Comment: It would be slightly faster to include the json array within the php file rather than using file_get_contents()

Answer (score 1):

[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is what you're looking for. It will put the entire contents of the file into a string.

```
$json = file_get_contents('dir/jsondata.json');
```

Comment: In case the remote file is  csv: like     xyz.com/dir/data.csv

Comment: file_get_contents() will work with any file type. If using a CSV file, you'd have to parse through the string to create your JSON array.

Comment: Is so, how to create the json array from the csv file

Comment: That is a whole new question entirely. I suggest you ask a new question and post a link to it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003164/get-json-array-from-remote-csv-in-php